# How do I clear the print area in Office.js?

Tags: javascript, printing, office-js, office-addins

Is there a way to clear the print area in Office.js? I have already tried setPrintArea(null) to do this, but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to pass an empty string to the [setPrintArea](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.pagelayout?view=excel-js-preview#excel-excel-pagelayout-setprintarea-member(1)) method.